# A weapon-of-choice for a Chinese marksman

Tags: weapons, firearms

For the backstory of a character of the wife of a Chinese marksman who has to escape China after her husband is accused of treason. She decides to take her husband's trusty rifle. It has to be a sniper rifle used by the Chinese army, and for the purpose of the story, it cannot be a massive anti-material one.

Comment: Answered, but I suspect that there is a better Stack for this question.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Trickyni. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is not for the use of storytelling, but for describing the world in which your story takes place. In this case, your question concerns determining the details of a world that already exists (i.e., Earth). I downvoted due to a clear lack of research and am voting to close because this isn't a worldbuilding question.

Comment: I don't see how this question has anything to do with worldbuilding ...

Comment: There's a big different between a _standard issue rifle_, and the ***"rifle of choice"***. Furthermore, being a marksman/military man doesn't mean that you are allowed to bring your weapon home, and it also doesn't mean the wife would know how to operate said rifle, or even have any decent amount of ammunition on hand to use with it. Last but not least, when fleeing the authorities, a bulky sniper rifle is not something you're gonna be able to carry through the streets. You're better off being inconspicuous, and staying hidden, not engaging in the assassination of government officials.

Comment: While I apologize for misunderstanding what this community was about, I Have to thank you for the warm welcome, and thank you, andreiROM, for pointing out this rather embarrassing flaw in my backstory. I couldn't do it, but if any of you could delete this question, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like most Soviet-era equipment, the SVD Dragunov rifle was copied by Chinese (as the type 79/85)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at the Chinese NSG-85 (2010) sniper rifle or the NORINCO Type 79 (SVD) (1979).

The website prevents taking quotations of its text.

Source: [NORINCO NSG-85 Semi-Automatic Sniper Rifle](http://www.militaryfactory.com/smallarms/detail.asp?smallarms_id=919)

Source: [NORINCO Type 79 (SVD) Semi-Automatic Sniper Rifle](http://www.militaryfactory.com/smallarms/detail.asp?smallarms_id=611)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a timeframe, what about the [QBU-88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBU-88)

Otherwise there are lots of [Pages on the webz](https://www.google.de/#q=chinese+sniper+rifle)